# What is mirror wisdom?

Tags: wisdom

What is the right way to understand (or apply) mirror wisdom?  Is it buddha-nature, bodhisattva (ripe for awakening), or both?  Is it cultivated, or does it spring up naturally with enlightenment?  If it's a method, how can it be utilized to curb conceit?  Is it a prerequisite for non-duality?  Does it have a place in mindfulness meditation?

EDIT: from what i understand it's one of five wisdom types.  that's about all i know.  that and wondering about the people across from me on the subway, when i think maybe this is when i should work with the mirroring...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_wisdoms

Comment: [Ādarśa-jñāna](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/adarshajnana)

Comment: There is no such thing as mirror wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

Mirror wisdom is when you realize reality and dūkha are two sides of the same coin. When you avoid dukkha, you avoid reality - this is fine for a lifetime, but then what?  Eventually you have to settle down - like a second or third wife.

Here is a real contraction: [The Benefits of Love](https://suttacentral.net/an11.15/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=sidebyside&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin)

Answer (score -2):

A segment from *'Saved by the Light of the Buddha Within'...*
My new understandings of what many call **'God -The Holy Spirit'** - resulting from some of the extraordinary ongoing after-effects relating to my NDE...

***Myoho-Renge-Kyo***

Represents the identity of what some scientists are now referring to as the unified field of consciousnesses. In other words, it’s the essence of all existence and non-existence – the ultimate creative force behind planets, stars, nebulae, people, animals, trees, fish, birds, and all phenomena, manifest or latent. All matter and intelligence are simply waves or ripples manifesting to and from this core source.

**Consciousness (enlightenment)**

Is it self the actual creator of everything that exists now, ever existed in the past, or will exist in the future – right down to the minutest particles of dust – each being an individual ripple or wave.

The big difference between chanting *Nam-Myoho-Renge-Kyo* and most other conventional prayers is that instead of depending on a ‘*middleman*’ to connect us to our state of inner enlightenment, we’re able to do it ourselves. That’s because chanting *Nam-Myoho-Renge-Kyo* allows us to tap directly into our enlightened state by way of this self-produced sound vibration.

**‘Who or What Is God?’**

If we compare the concept of God being a separate entity that is forever watching down on us, to the teachings of *Nichiren*, it makes more sense to me that the true omnipotence, omniscience and omnipresence of what most people perceive to be God, is the fantastic state of enlightenment that exists within each of us.

Some say that God is an entity that’s beyond physical matter – I think that the vast amount of information continuously being conveyed via electromagnetic waves in today’s world gives us proof of how an invisible state of God could indeed exist.

For example, it’s now widely known that specific data relayed by way of electromagnetic waves has the potential to help bring about extraordinary and powerful effects – including an instant global awareness of something or a mass emotional reaction.

It’s also common knowledge that these invisible waves can easily be used to detonate a bomb or to enable *NASA* to control the movements of a robot as far away as the Moon or Mars – none of which is possible without a receiver to decode the information that’s being transmitted. Without the receiver, the data would remain impotent.

In a very similar way, we need to have our own ‘receiver’ switched on so that we can activate a clear and precise understanding of our own life, all other life and what everything else in existence is.

Chanting *Nam-Myoho-Renge-Kyo* each day helps us to achieve this because it allows us to reach the core of our enlightenment and keep it switched on. That’s because *Myoho-Renge-Kyo* represents the identity of what scientists now refer to as the unified field of consciousnesses.

To break it down – ***Myoho*** represents *the Law of manifestation* and *latency (Nature)* and consists of two alternating states. For example:-

**The state of *Myo***

Is where everything in life that’s not obvious to us exists – including our stored memories when we’re not thinking about them – our hidden potential and inner emotions whenever they’re dormant – our desires, our fears, our wisdom, happiness, karma and more importantly, our enlightenment.

**The other state *ho***

Is where everything in Life exists whenever it becomes evident to us, such as when a thought pops up from within our memory – whenever we experience or express our emotions – or whenever a good or bad cause manifests as an effect from our karma.

When anything becomes apparent, it merely means that it’s come out of the state of *Myo* (dormancy/latency) and into a state of *ho* (manifestation). It’s the difference between consciousness and unconsciousness, being awake or asleep, or knowing and not knowing.

**The second law – *Renge***

*Ren* meaning **cause** and *ge* meaning **effect**, governs and controls the functions of *Myoho* – these two laws of *Myoho* and *Renge*, not only function together simultaneously but also underlies all spiritual and physical existence.

**The final and third part of the tri-combination – *Kyo***

is the Law that allows *Myoho* to integrate with *Renge* – or vice versa. It’s the great, invisible thread of energy that fuses and connects all Life and matter – as well as the past, present and future. It’s also sometimes termed *The Universal Law of Communication* – perhaps it could even be compared with the *string theory* that many scientists now suspect exists.

Just as the cells in our body, our thoughts, feelings and everything else is continually fluctuating within us – all that exists in the world around us and beyond is also in a constant state of flux – constantly controlled by these *Three fundamental laws*.

In fact, more things are going back and forth between the two states of *Myo* and *ho* in a single moment than it would ever be possible to calculate or describe. And it doesn’t matter how big or small, famous or trivial anything or anyone may appear to be, everything that’s ever existed in the past, exists now or will exist in the future, exists only because of the workings of ***the Laws Myoho-Renge-Kyo*** – the basis of, and if they didn’t function, neither we nor anything else could go on existing.

That’s because all forms of existence, including the seasons, day, night, birth, death and so on, are moving forward in an ongoing flow of continuation – rhythmically reverting back and forth between the two fundamental states of *Myo* and *ho* in absolute accordance with *Renge* – and by way of *Kyo*.
Even stars are dying and being reborn under the workings of what the combination *‘Myoho-Renge-Kyo’* represents.

***Nam, or Namu*** – which mean the same thing, are vibrational passwords or keys that allow us to reach deep into our life and fuse with or become one with ‘Myoho-Renge-Kyo’.
On a more personal level, nothing ever happens by chance or coincidence, it’s the causes that we’ve made in our past, or are presently making, that determine how these laws function uniquely in each of our lives – as well as the environment from moment to moment.

By facing east, in harmony with the direction that the Earth is spinning, and chanting ***Nam-Myoho-Renge-Kyo*** for a minimum of, let’s say, ten minutes daily to start with, any of us can experience actual proof of its positive effects in our lives – even if it only makes us feel good on the inside, there will be a definite positive effect.

That’s because we’re able to pierce through the thickest layers of our karma and activate our inherent Buddha Nature (our enlightened state). By so doing, we’re then able to bring forth the wisdom and good fortune that we need to challenge, overcome and change our adverse circumstances – turn them into positive ones – or manifest and gain even greater fulfilment in our daily lives from our accumulated ***good karma.***

This also allows us to bring forth the wisdom that can free us from the ignorance and stupidity that’s preventing us from accepting and being proud of the person that we indeed are – regardless of our race, colour, gender or sexuality. We’re also able to see and understand our circumstances and the environment far more clearly, as well as attract and connect with any needed external beneficial forces and situations.

As I’ve already mentioned, everything is subject to *the law of Cause and Effect* – the ‘actual-proof-strength’ resulting from chanting *Nam-Myoho-Renge-Kyo* always depends on our determination, sincerity and dedication.
For example, the levels of difference could be compared to making a sound on a piano, creating a melody, producing a great song, and so on. Something else that’s very important to always respect and acknowledge is that *the Law (or if you prefer God)* is in everyone and everything.

**NB:** There are frightening and disturbing sounds, and there are tranquil and relaxing sounds. It’s the emotional result of any noise or sound that can trigger off a mood or even instantly change one.

When chanting *Nam-Myoho-Renge-Kyo* each day, we are producing a sound vibration that’s the password to our ***true inner-self*** – this soon becomes apparent when you start reassessing your views on various things – such as your fears and desires etc. The best way to get the desired result when chanting is not to view things conventionally – rather than reaching out to an external source, we need to reach into our own lives and bring our needs and desires to fruition from within – including the good fortune and strength to achieve any help that we may need.

Chanting *Nam-Myoho-Renge-Kyo* also reaches out externally and draws us towards, or draws towards us, what we need to make us happy from our environment. For example, it helps us to be in the right place at the right time – to make better choices and decisions and so forth. We need to think of it as a seed within us that we’re watering and bringing sunshine to for it to grow, blossom and bring forth fruit or flowers.

It’s also important to understand that everything we need in life, including the answer to every question and the potential to achieve every dream, already exists within us.

Comment: Your post looks good, but remember to use paragraphs. Welcome!

Comment: This was copy-and-pasted from elsewhere e.g. perhaps [here](https://www.facebook.com/Nassim.Haramein.official/posts/d41d8cd9/782869521904308/?locale=hi_IN) and [here](https://abhishekmunian.medium.com/a-note-on-nichiren-buddhism-16c05ce9b78c) and many other places.